# Android Studio - Inflar PopupMenu con layout personalizado?

Tags: android-studio, popup

trato de inflar el popupmenu con un layout personalizado, no quiero cargarlo desde el resources "menu". Tengo el siguiente código:

```
imageButtonMasOpciones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), imageButtonMasOpciones);

            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Item : " + menuItem.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

en ese código se crea bien el popupMenu, pero cuando reemplazo esta linea de código:

```
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
```

por esta:

```
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, popup.getMenu());
```

la aplicación se cierra

Comment: has visto si existe este layout `(R.layout.popup`

Comment: has visto si existe este layput `(R.layout.popup`

Comment: Si, ya lo revise, existe.

Answer (score 0):

En tu directorio menu: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alli debes crear tu propio popup_menu
y dentro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/popupBorrar"
    android:title ="Borrar"
    />
</menu>
```

cada item es una opcion de tu popup menu, si quieres algo con mas vista y mas diseño creo que podrias implementar `DialogFragment`

Comment: ahh pues en el directorio menu no existe el archivo xml, porque yo lo que quiero hacer es como tu dices algo con mas vistas y diseños mas personalizados, con el dialog fragment puedo lograr ese efecto de desplegue del PopupMenu?

Comment: SI es como una modal que puedes comunicar por interfaces con tu acivity